# Danganronpa - What is supposed to happen if there are 2 or 3 players left?

Tags: danganronpa

So I just heard of this anime that resembles the Mafia/Wolf game.

> However, when Makoto arrives inside the Academy, he loses consciousness and wakes up locked inside the school, where he meets fourteen other newly picked Ultimate students who are in the same situation as him. It is there that a sadistic, remote-controlled bear named Monokuma appears before them, telling them they will be imprisoned in the academy for the rest of their lives, and that they will be put to death if they violate any of the schools rules. He offers only one way for students to "graduate" from the academy: murder another student and not be identified as the culprit.

So if the culprit is correctly identified (majority vote or something?), culprit gets executed. If not, everyone but culprit gets executed.

What is supposed to happen if there are 2 or 3 players left?

I'm not so naive as to think that what is supposed to happen is what actually happens, but I think there should be a rule for that.

If there is no explanation in the anime or other media, please state such and if applicable why no explanation is needed (I might be overlooking something obvious).

Liar Game had a rule as to what happens in Minority Rule if there are only 2 players left. There was some detail about it. I don't think explaining that rule spoils the manga or series: If there are 2 left, the prize is split. To drop out, half of the prize must be given back, whatever the amount of the prize is (half of the full 2.1 billion or half of 1.05 billion).

PS I'm done with the anime. Go ahead and spoil other media. But please use spoiler tags for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monokuma (the robot bear), has

> a fetish for despair.

And by 'Monokuma',

> I refer to main villain (whom I will be shortening to MV from now on) of the anime who controls Monokuma. The exact reason MV imprisoned those 14 students: to make them feel despair, and enjoy it.

In fact, the reason Monokuma created the rule that

> If you murder one of your classmates and not get caught as the culprit, you can escape

is precisely so that

> the classmates who had an attachment to the victim will mourn his/her death, and the ones who became friends with the culprit, will feel guilty.

As to what would happen if only 2 or 3, or even only 1 will remain...

> It is never exactly stated what would happen if only 2 or 3, or even only 1 will remain (at the end 7 or 8 students remain), but judging by the MV's fetish for despair, MV would probably (remember there is no exact proof what she would do, so I used the word probably)
>
>  A) not let any of the remaining 1/2/3 student/s go, unless they either murder each other, or will remain in the school for the rest of their life, feeling eternal despair.
>
>  B) kill them, because MV will either get bored of them or MV will be annoyed by how optimistic they are about life, since the whole point of locking them in school was to enjoy people's despair, and when their despair becomes repetitive, or they don't feel any despair, MV's forced to kill/get rid of them.

### Note:

- Danganronpa was originally a video game series. The anime was released in order to commercialize the first video game of the series, which the plot of the anime is based on.
- Because the video game is long, whereas the anime is only 12 episodes, it's rushed and left out a lot of details from the video game.
- > Also, in the second game it's revealed that the MV did in fact have a back-up plan for when MV would get bored or annoyed of the 14 students MV's currently watching. In the anime, MV made other schools, and MV imprisoned other students as well, in order to watch them despair once MV would have had enough of the current students.