# In danganronpa, what happens in a drawn vote?

Tags: danganronpa

Unlike the games in [Liar Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_Game), the rules of a Danganronpa game are sometimes made up or stated midway, which for me kind of sucks but is tolerable so long as the rules are consistent.

In Liar Game, afaik, the dealers have always accounted for all possible situations so whenever there are changes in the game, they state it outright. For example, in games involving voting, the dealers have stated what happens in the event of a draw. Eg [Minority Rule](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giI29--lEwI&t=76s)

---

Suppose in a Danganronpa game starting with 15 students,

1. all murders are **committed by exactly one person** (no collaborative murders during the act, but before or after the act is fine, assuming there would be some incentive) and **to exactly one person** (no multiple victims)
2. **all murderers are successfully guessed and convicted** (iirc, this is by majority vote) so long as there are more than 3 players
3. **No one dies in a way other than being murdered.** So, no one messes with Monokuma, dies of an accident, dies of health conditions (eg asthma) or naturally (eg old age), etc, but suicide is fine.
4. **No murders will be hidden from the other students indefinitely**, as in all corpses will be discovered or if the body is burned, then there will be enough evidence to say a murder has taken place and thus enough evidence for a classroom trial to be called.

Assuming the above situation is consistent internally and externally consistent with the initial set up of a Danganronpa game, such game will eventually come down to 3 students, whom I'm going to call Kotonoha, Yuno and Mion.

Suppose further:

1. The game continues (so it's not declared a draw between the 3).
2. Yuno dies, not of suicide or [accident](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29326/who-is-to-say-if-someone-is-murdered) but murdered by Kotonoha or Mion.
3. If there is a corpse (body is not burned or anything), it will be discovered. If none, Yuno's death is discovered in another way.
4. [Despite insufficient witnesses, a classroom trial will be called.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29331/in-danganronpa-how-can-a-classroom-trial-be-called-if-there-are-only-2-witnesse)

**Questions**:

1. **So what happens in the event of a drawn vote between the two?**
2. **Generally**, whenever there are an even number of voters in a classroom trial, what happens in the event of a drawn vote? Since it's not a majority, everyone but the culprit dies?

**I would like to know what are the stated rules regarding this, if any, and from any media.**

---

If I made any logical errors either internally (inconsistent with itself) or externally (inconsistent with Danganronpa), please point them out.

PS I'm done with the anime. Go ahead and spoil other media. But please use spoiler tags for others.

PPS Re 'Kotonoha, Yuno and Mion'

> Don't spoil please re 'Mion'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to both these questions:

1. [In danganronpa, what happens in a drawn vote?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29330/in-danganronpa-what-happens-in-a-drawn-vote)
2. [In Danganronpa, how can a classroom trial be called if there are only 2 witnesses available?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29331/in-danganronpa-how-can-a-classroom-trial-be-called-if-there-are-only-2-witnesse)

## Part I - Guess for the in general case

> A drawn vote is the same as if there's a majority vote and it's not the killer: The killer is technically not majority voted. Therefore, the killer wins.

Consequently, this explains...

1 - why Monokuma didn't say anything about a drawn vote: There's no need to say this because it's already included.

The point is the killer has to be voted out. A drawn vote does not accomplish this. There's no need to say that killers have draw odds like [chess / 9LX armageddon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_chess#Armageddon) because it's implied.

Of course, it would've been nice for Monokuma to just say this to clarify / emphasise anyway.

Credit for guess: [clueanalysis2596 from YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/@clueanalysis2596)

2 - the difference with Liar Game's [Minority Rule](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giI29--lEwI&t=76s):

- In the event there are 2 remaining in Minority Rule, the 2 are symmetric. There's no reason to favour 1 over the other, but of course you could force a tiebreak by making them play poker or whatever.
- In Danganronpa, there's definitely an asymmetry between the killer and the non-killer. It's the same asymmetry that forms the basis for the principle of innocent until proven guilty.

## Part II - Guess for when it comes down to 3 people:

Whoever kills someone 1st wins the whole game assuming a trial is called despite insufficient witnesses.

In the trial, each of the 2 remaining people just vote the other off. There's no majority against the killer, and that's that.

## Part III - the assumptions

A big assumption here is the 1 murderer - 1 victim thing. If there were 4 people left, then maybe the next killer would likely kill 2 people instead of just 1 person.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** "Additional school regulations may be added if necessary"

As unsatisfying as it is, the only answer as to what happens in the event of a draw during voting is we do not know. It has never occurred and Monokuma would likely have just made up a rule on the fly if it ever did (it wouldn't be the first time he made up rules when it suited him).

It should also be noted the elaborate setup in the question is unnecessary, a draw is always possible whether there is an even or odd number of students and even in the first class trial of a killing game, the vote isn't strictly guilty / not guilty like it is in a real criminal trial by jury, you vote for a person and nothing stops multiple people from having the same number of votes. In a hypothetical game with 16 students where one has died and its come time to vote, if 7 people vote for student A, 7 people vote for student B and the last person votes for anyone else the vote is tied.

The only rules that pertain to voting are the same across all 3 main games: Rule #8-9 (D1: THH), #6-7 (D2: GD), #3-4 (DV3: KH) "If the blackened is exposed during the class trial, they alone will be executed" and "If the blackened is not exposed, all remaining students will be executed." These rules assume that voting will single out a single person and this has always been true. Whether these cover ties is up in the air, you could argue so long as one of the people who is tied for most votes is the blackened it counts but Monokuma might also disallow ties and force another vote (whatever he thinks will cause more despair). With that in mind the relevant rule is "**Additional school regulations may be added if necessary**".

At various points in the series ambiguity with the rules or the setup of the games come into question forcing Monokuma to add a rule such as Rule #15 in DV3 "If two different murders by different murderers occur at the same time, only the one whose victim was found first will be the blackened". Which is a natural question to raise in the event of a double kill. As well as Rule #11 in D1 "The guilty party may only kill a maximum of two people during any single 'Killing Game.'" Which assures students a serial killer can't kill everyone else and win by default. If a relevant situation ever came up Monokuma would have figured something out but what form that solution would have taken is left to speculation

Comment: Relevant? related? anything to say there? https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29331/in-danganronpa-how-can-a-classroom-trial-be-called-if-there-are-only-2-witnesse or this? https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29332/in-danganronpa-how-can-a-classroom-trial-be-called-if-there-is-no-corpse or that? https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29268/danganronpa-what-is-supposed-to-happen-if-there-are-2-or-3-players-left

Comment: I posted an answer. Lemme know what you think please. My answer: A drawn vote is the same as if there's a majority vote and it's not the killer: The killer is technically not majority voted.

Therefore, the killer wins.